# Is Frame-Options a standard or it's only a draft with no schedule to approve?

Tags: security, x-frame-options

OWASP has a [page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers) where they suggest to use x-frame-options and frame-options to prevent clickjacking. The latter is defined as a [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gondrom-frame-options-02) few yeards ago, but I cannot find the information on any implementation or acceptance of this draft. Is it accepted, is it planned to or in other words what is it's status and should we be adding it or only use x-frame-options for now.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7034

Comment: As I understand that's not standard either since it has status "Informational", not sure though what it means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Frame-Options` is not standard.

The new standard is to use [CSP's `frame-ancestors` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#frame-ancestors).

> The frame-ancestors  directive specifies valid parents that may embed
>   a page using the `<frame>` and `<iframe>` elements. This directive is not
>   supported in the  element or by the
>   Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only header field.

As this is a new standard ([see browser support here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy)), it is advised to also use [`X-Frame-Options`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers) is the meantime while all browsers your platform supports either catch up or fizzle out.

Comment: Can you use frame-ancestors to do full blocking (like DENY)? It's a bit unclear how it will behave without this directive (I suppose allow all).

Comment: It's a whitelist, so if you don't enter any sources it will deny all.

Comment: So, not present = allow all, present with empty list = block all. Great, thank you for your help!

Comment: It does say here (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP11/#directive-frame-ancestors) really that you can use 'none' for that.

Answer (score 1):

It is advised that the server responds with an `X-Frame-Options` header for irrespective of whether or not the draft has been approved. I have pulled the following content from [Acunetix](http://acunetix.com/vulnerabilities/web/clickjacking--x-frame-options-header-missing) vulnerability description:

> Clickjacking (User Interface redress attack, UI redress attack, UI redressing) is a malicious technique of tricking a Web user into clicking on something different from what the user perceives they are clicking on, thus potentially revealing confidential information or taking control of their computer while clicking on seemingly innocuous web pages.

My impression is that the draft is not standardized (atleast at the time of this post) because `X-Frame-Options` is implemented differently through different browsers, leading to unintended results and behavior—however, this is just my speculation and could be for completely different reasons.